# Access databases with libGDX on Android AND iOS

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, libgdx

We are a group of students who are doing a 3D game with libGDX. We want to save the multi-user profiles and best scores of each level in database. Also as the plan, our game should be released on Android, desktop and iOS. So we need to find a cross-platform database interface.

Unfortunately we just found this one, which only supports android and desktop with SQLite:
https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite

What is the best practice to access database with libGDX on iOS?

As we checked, iOS supports SQLite, but it is Objective-C libraries, and we are not familiar with how to interactive with Objective-C objects from java. If you can give us some information about that, it is also very appreciated.

Comment: I think roboVM might support jdbc / sqlite already anyway.